# Program that broadcast a part of a screen to the whole screen

Tags: windows

I was trying to watch some video on a site and the fullscreen option wasn't working so I tried to find a program that can project a part of a screen to the whole screen but I didn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

Windows provide the magnifier utility builtin as part of its core package.

You can use <kbd>windos</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to initiate.

There is docked mode in it which you can use.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/11542/windows-use-magnifier-to-make-things-easier-to-see